# Understanding a table's structure/schema in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I wanted to reach out to ask if there is a practical way of finding out a given table's structure/schema e.g.,the column names and example row data inserted into the table(like the head function in python) if you only have the table name. I have access to several tables in my current role, however, a person who developed the tables left the team I am on. I was interested in examining the tables closer via SQL Assistant in Teradata (these tables often contain often hundreds of thousands of rows hence there are issues of hitting CPU exception criteria errors).

I have tried the following select statement, but there is an issue of hitting internal CPU exception criteria limits.

> SELECT top10 * FROM dbc.table1

Thank you in advance for any tips/advice!

Comment: If `table1` is a table a TOP should use almost no CPU. Are you sure it's a table and not a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of these commands to get table's structure details in `teradata`

```
SHOW TABLE Database_Name.Table_Name;
```

or

```
HELP TABLE Database_Name.Table_Name;
```

It shows the table structure details

Comment: Hi Eshirvana, this helped! Thank you!

Comment: @matc88 you are welcome , to help the community please accept this as an answer, if it answered your question , thanks